# How to add internet accsess to container in docker compose?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

```
    ---
version: "3.6"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${APP_POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${APP_POSTGRES_PASS:-postgres}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${APP_POSTGRES_DB:-my_proj}
    ports:
      - "5566:5432"
  server:
    container_name: my_proj_app
    hostname: my_proj_app
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - PORT=8080
      - HOST=my_proj_app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml
I can't ping google.com from my_proj_app container.
Have anybody ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is explained here https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ : you used the **host network mode** which cannot access outside network, unlike the **NAT**.

> Host mode networking can be useful to optimize performance, and in situations where a container needs to handle a large range of ports, as it does not require network address translation (NAT), and no “userland-proxy” is created for each port.

Try commenting `network_mode: host`.

Comment: commenting doesn't help (

Comment: Please, tell me if you resolve host names inside container or not.

Comment: no, I have just commented network_mode: host

Comment: Sorry, but my question was: do you resolve host names inside the container? Pinging `google.com` by `RUN ping google.com` prints the IP address?

Comment: docker exec my_proj_app ping google.com   this command hangs

Comment: but ping from container start script completes well